# Observer - get the most last value

Tags: rxjs, state, observers

I need to send a request with a large amount of data. Those data come from 6 different components - so basically it is very hard to do it without a `reactive approach`. I decided to do something like `ngrx component store` implementation (because of some reasons I've decided to implement it on my own).

I've created a store implementation that is being provided as a component provider, created a state which is being held in `BehaviorSubject`, created a simple `select` function which maps the state to needed data. In `ngOnInit Parent Component` I made a request to the backend server to fetch `foos`, setting a `foo.isLoading` flag. Then I am subscribing and listened to `foo.data` changes. If it does - I am calling backend server - I am setting `boo.isLoading` and I am fetching `boos`.

`Foos` and `Boos` are fetched correctly but there is an issue with `boo.isLoading` flag - and I believe it comes from the order of calling state observers. Steps:

1. foo.isLoading is set to true
2. foo.data is set to backend response, foo.isLoading is set to false
3. then foo observer receives value and makes an HTTP request to get boos.
4. boo.isLoading is set to true and sends an HTTP request
5. boo.isLoading observers receives true
6. but since the state was changed twice - boo.isLoading observers haven't received the first value which now they do, so the most last received value is false

Any ideas on how to solve it? I've tried with `switchMap` state to `of(state)` so the previous subscription should be canceled when the new value "arrives" but it doesn't work.

Source code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qgbdxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a read to trigger a write in this selector.

```
this.parentStore.select(state => state.foo.data).pipe(
   filter(data => !!data),
   tap(_ => this.parentStore.loadBooData())
).subscribe();
```

And since `FooLoadCompletion` and `BooLoadStart` processes are synchronous, the order of execution is messing with your flow.

I'll try to explain it.

The FooLoadComplete triggers the execution of the following selectors in this order, due to the moment they subscribe.

```
onFooLoadComplete
   selector(foo.data).next(['a','b','c','d'])
   selector(foo.isLoading).next(false)
   selector(boo.isLoading).next(false)
```

But since your triggering the `BooLoadStart` side effect in the foo.data selector the execution order ends up being like this.

```
onFooLoadComplete
  selector(foo.data).next(yourData)
    BooLoadStart
      selector(foo.isLoading).next(false)
      selector(boo.isLoading).next(true)
  selector(foo.isLoading).next(false)
  selector(boo.isLoading).next(false)
```

So the `boo.isLoading` values get processed in the selector in the inverse order that you expect. And that is why the selector is printing `false`.

To avoid this kind of problems you should keep your READ and WRITE pipelines independent.

In the code your supplying you could solve it removing the foo.data selector side effect and calling to `loadBooData` in the setTimeout of `loadFooData`

```
loadFooData() {
  this.state.next({
    ...this.state.value,
    foo: {
      ...this.state.value.foo,
      isLoading: true
    }
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.state.next({
      ...this.state.value,
      foo: {
        ...this.state.value.foo,
        isLoading: false,
        data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      }
    })

    this.loadBooData();

  }, 2000)
}
```

Hope to have helped

cheers

Comment: I totally understood an issue - but I thought, maybe there is a way to `reactify` it - as I said - I have 6 different variables that changes should trigger boo fetch action. But I guess it's not possible.

Comment: You can do it in a reactive way if you want. You can do something like the httpClient service, and return observables from the methods of your store and then combine and chain them in the component as you need and trigger the execution with a subscription.